# Регулярное выражение поиска тега html java

Tags: java, html, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть значение атрибута href и мне надо найти весь тег  с этим атрибутом на html;

Например, известно значение href: example.htm, результат должен быть:

`<a class = "" href="example.htm">example</a>` - true

`<a \n href='example.htm'><p>example \n</p></a>` - true

`<a href="example.htm">example <a href=""></a></a>` - false

Вот я сделал уже `<a\\s[^<]+"+"example.htm"+"[\\s\\S.]*?</a>`, но оно не удовлетворяет последний пример.

Comment: Парсить HTML регулярками — бессмысленно, это невозможно. https://habrahabr.ru/post/175179/#comment_6086921 Лучше возмите полноценный парсер HTML.

Comment: Третий пример - невалидный html.

Comment: у меня есть такой баг на сайте и если регулярка пройдет, то я закомментирую  пол html страницы

Answer (score 0):

```
/<a[^>]*example.htm[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/gi
```

Тест онлайн:  https://regex101.com/r/aoywwt/1